# Install Firefox non-ESR version in raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, chromium, web-browsers, google-chrome

I know it's impossible to install Chrome (not chromium) on a raspberry pi, and I know that the standard Firefox version for raspberry is Firefox-esr now. But there are some applications that are only compatible with either chrome or firefox non-esr. 
Is there a way to install the non-esr version of Firefox in a raspberry pi? it's ok if the solution involves changing the OS.

Alternatively, is there a way to get chromium to work as Chrome in most aspects? like installing plugins per example?

The final objective is to be able to run a website that I used to be able to run in Chromium, but all of the sudden shows the following message:
 "Your browser cannot run this application, Please install Chrome or Firefox"

Thanks for the help

Comment: This "question" is too vague. Have you tried [Vivaldi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/vivaldi/)?

Comment: @Milliways, thanks for your answer. I just tried vivaldi, the curious thing is that I tried first on windows computer, and Vivaldi was able to run the website I am trying to run, but when I installed it on my raspberry pi, it shows the same message, saying that my browser isn't compatible. Any ideas?